# delete records from mysql where it like number

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete records from mysql using php

the field name: Week

Week records values as below:

```
200801
200802
200803
200804
200805
etc
```

I created TextField named "tYear", user will insert first 4 numbers from the left and sql statement should remove all the records starting with them, example ... if the user insert 2008 all the above records as they starting with 2008 should be removed.

I am using sql statement as below but it's not working

```
$sql= "DELETE from sites WHERE Week like '". $_POST['tYear']."'";
$results = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your query is :
    $sql= "DELETE from sites WHERE Week like '". $_POST['tYear']."'";

and with `like` in mysql you have to use `like '%%' or like '%'` for so use :

```
$sql= "DELETE from sites WHERE 
        Week like '%". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tYear'])."%'";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use LIKE

```
$sql= "DELETE FROM `sites` WHERE `Week` LIKE '". (int)$_POST['tYear']."%'";
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help and your fast reply, the above statement from jogesh_p is working good with me :)

Comment: SQL injection ! Just POST % for massive data loss.

Comment: That's why I've passed `(int)` in front of `$_POST`. How do you make my query mess with database?

Comment: POST 2 then. LIKE '2%' will also delete everything.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$sql= "DELETE from sites WHERE Week like '". $_POST['tYear']."%'"
```